# Google Cloud Build cannot trigger build: no such blob

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I had an app engine app with multiple services running and since stopping and restarting it (from the Dashboard buttons) CloudBuild doesn't want to function anymore.

I set up a trigger to run on pushes to certain branches and when I trigger it either manually or automatically by pushing commits it doesn't even register as a started build but instead I am presented with a message:

`Failed to trigger build: <app-engine-name>/<repo-name>:cloudbuild.yaml: No such blob refs/heads/<repo-branch-name>:cloudbuild.yaml`

without any links to follow or any other helpful thing.

Comment: Is your `cloudbuild.yaml` file in your repository?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, yes, it is

Comment: Post the contents of cloudbuild.yaml that is in your repository. Can you deploy manually?

Comment: Also include the logs from Cloud Build.

Comment: @JohnHanley I posted the contents of `cloudbuild.yaml`. There were no logs in StackDriver associated with building and deployments that I could find. I should also mention that I have another app on the same app engine with an almost identical `cloudbuild.yaml` configuration and that one works well

Comment: Go to Cloud Build in the console. Go to Triggers. Click Run Trigger. Go to History. Click on the last build. Post the logs for the last build.

Comment: The Cloud Build logs are the same that you will find in Stackdriver -> Cloud Build. If you do not see logs in Stackdriver, maybe you have a permissions problem with the service account (PROJECT_ID@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com). Check the IAM permissions and post in your question.

Comment: When I click run trigger I get the error that I mentioned and there is NOTHING in History, the build doesn't even start in order to be registered in the history.

Comment: Disable the current Build Trigger. Create a new Build Trigger and try again.

Comment: I did that multiple times both yesterday and today. I will try deploying manually

Comment: turns out Google was having trouble accessing our repos on Bitbucket and would not sync properly. I will update the question.

Comment: @DanCornilescu did that and removed the part about the fix from the quesiton's details

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was Google Cloud Build accessing the repo on Bitbucket. After two factor auth was activated on Bitbucket Google was failing to sync the information, would not say this properly and would simply be using a very outdated version of what it mirrored.

The problem was fixed by disconnecting everything related to Bitbucket and reconnecting it again and waiting a couple of minutes for the settings to sync.